# adt eclipse bundle 02-07-2014 UPDATE

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, bundle, adt

Have used the newest bundle provided by the android developers site. Everything is fine but when I try and download the adt plugin it gives this error:

Installing Software has encountered an error

`Details: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature,23.0.2.1259578
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature,23.0.2.1259578
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature,23.0.2.1259578
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature,23.0.2.1259578
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,23.0.2.1259578
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature,23.0.2.1259578
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature,23.0.2.1259578`

Any idea on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: The bundle already has ADT in it. That's why it's a bundle.

Comment: @nitind yeah sorry meant when I want to update the adt it shows me this error. Any idea on what I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just uncheck the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" before starting to install.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're using "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" as your download link.  The default ones are wrong - at least in my dropdown list.

Comment: In some cases is htts the default instead of https the right value!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the package itself has bug they are resolving it.

Better you can download the new ADT bundle in android developers site.

This bundle provides new version of ADT v23 along with sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have the same issue. It seems this is an open issue :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72912

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction:

Troubleshooting ADT Installation
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Download the ADT-23.0.2.zip manually and follow the instruction to update it.
This will solve your problem.

Comment: Probably best to also describe why the error happened instead of just posting the link and state 'This will solve your problem'.

Answer (score 0):

From the experience l had with Eclipse l removed the forward slash at the end of the following statement  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse it will append the forward slash on its own. l guess eclipse confused about this. l hope it will work for others